# Postgres: count(*) vs count(id)

Tags: postgresql, optimization, count

I saw in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) the difference between `count(*)` and `count(pk)`.  I had been using `count(pk)` (where `pk` is a `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`) not knowing about the existence of `count(*)`.

My question is about Postgres' internal optimizations. Is it smart enough to pick up that a `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` is going to exist in every row and never be false and just count rows or will it do redundant predicate checks for each row?  I agree that this is probably too much of a pointless optimization but I'm just curious.

I took a look at the output of `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN VERBOSE` for `count(*)`, `count(id)` and `count(id > 50)` to see if `EXPLAIN` mentioned checking the predicates in its output. It doesn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got consistent results in my repeated tests with various versions over the last years:
`count(*)` is faster than `count(pk)`. It is also shorter and most of the time it better fits what is tested: the existence of a row.

Concerning:

> Is Postgres smart enough to pick up that a `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` is going
> to exist in every row and never be false

The only relevant thing is the `NOT NULL` constraint. A `PRIMARY KEY` column is `NOT NULL` automatically. "serial" or "never false" are orthogonal to the question.

With `count(col)`, *if* PostgreSQL was trying to be smart and check the system catalog whether a column was `NOT NULL` and fall back to an equivalent `count(*)`, you'd still have one more look-up on a system table than with `count(*)`.

What's more, *any* column can contain `NULL` values after an `OUTER JOIN`. So the optimization not applicable to certain queries. Probably not worth the complication ...

As for `EXPLAIN` output, there *is* a hint:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM ...

Aggregate  (cost=4963.38..4963.43 rows=1 width=0) ...


EXPLAIN SELECT count(pk) FROM ...

Aggregate  (cost=4963.38..4963.43 rows=1 width=4) ...
```

Meaning, `count(col)` is **not** converted to `count(*)`, even if it's defined `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Is this still the case with the new versions? I think it wouldn't really need a lookup for *every* query - it could be cached.

Comment: Btw, with a `NOT NULL` column, the difference is *big* if you have a lot of rows. In our case with millions of rows, `COUNT(*)` is 3 times faster.  (Postgres 9.4)